# A pushout of a homotopy equivalence along

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homotopy-theory

Can anybody show me an example which prove that:

**A pushout of a homotopy equivalence along a arbitrary map (in Top) doesn't have to be a homotopy equivalence.**

I know that if we change "arbitrary map" to cofibration then the pushout have to be a homotopy equivalence, but I try to find an example which show that assumption of cofibration is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is a counterexample: Let $A=S^1\cup[1,2]\times\{0\}$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$.  For $f:A\to S^1$ take the map
$$
f(a)=\begin{cases}
a, &\text{if }a\in S^1\\
(1,0), &\text{if }a\in[1,2]
\end{cases}
$$
and for $g:A\to S^1$ take
$$
g(a)=\begin{cases}
a, &\text{if }a\in S^1\\
e^{2\pi i(t-1)}, &\text{if }a\in[1,2]
\end{cases}
$$
Now $f$ is a homotopy equivalence. But the induced map $S^1\to Y$ is a constant map since the pushout $Y=(S^1\sqcup S^1)/(f(a)\sim g(a))$ is a singleton.

Comment: There is typo: X=A (i can't change this because each edit must be at least 6 characters)

Comment: Yes, Thank you! but now I see even simpler solution. Let $B=A|_{[1,2]\times \{0\}}$ and $f'=f|_B$, $g'=g|_B$ then induced map $S^1 \to Y$ is still a constant map.